# swift / spritekit move then touch element

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uitouch

I'm currently working on a game in swift using spritekit. I've got my joystick working using [this](https://github.com/MitrophD/Swift-SpriteKit-Analog-Stick) library, and thats all good. I'm also moving the joystick to where the user taps using this code:

```
func updateJoystickPosition(pos: CGPoint) {
    let posX = -(self.sceneSize.width/2) + pos.x
    let posY = (self.sceneSize.height/2) - pos.y
    let newJoystickPos = CGPoint(x: posX, y: posY);

    self.joystick.position = newJoystickPos
}
```

which also works just fine, however, the joystick doesn't engage on that one tap. You have to tap on the actual joystick node for the joystick to engage, so obviously, i'd want the user to put their finger down on the screen and immediately be able to start moving it around to move the player.

the joystick it's self starts tracking with this function

```
open override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    print(touches)

    if let touch = touches.first, stick == atPoint(touch.location(in: self)) {
        tracking = true
        startHandler?()
    }
}
```

**Question: Is there anyway i can modify the `touchesBegan` function or any of my other functions to achieve the desired results?**

Comment: How does your "updateJoystickPosition" function get called? Did you add a different touch listener? cuz you could just use the same "touchesBegan" function, when a touch happens outside the joystick area, then just call the "tracking = true and startHandler?()" as well.

Comment: that function get's called from my gamescene's `touchesBegan` listener. The joystick library does its own. I put `tracking = true` and `startHandler?()` in a public function and tried calling it after the position is moved like `self.joystick.position = newJoystickPos` then`self.analogJoystick.touchJoystick()` but it doesn't seem to attach to it unfortunatly

Answer (score 1):

You have to override `touchesMoved(_ touches: ,with event:)` and in this method just processing all `touches`.

For example:

```
var startTouchingPoint = CGPoint.zero // property

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
       startTouchingPoint = touch.location(in: self.camera!))
       yourControllerPlace.position = startTouchingPoint
       stickOnYourJoystick.position = CGPoint.zero
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches { 
       let point = touch.location(in: self.camera!))
       let convertedPoint = CGPoint(x: point.x - startTouchingPoint.x,
                                    y: point.y - startTouchingPoint.y)

       stickOnYourJoystick.position = convertedPoint

    }
}
```